# Best way or refactoring a create or restore controller in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In my app users can create and soft-delete gateways something like Paypal. Users of a website can connect to the gateway and make payments.
I've written the logic in a transaction also locking a matching record (on `website` field) which was soft-deleted by the user because of race-condition. Read code for a better understanding.

**Already exists (soft-deleted)**
These gateways must be verified by admin, if the user submits different `website` and `description` fields in comparison to the matching record which was already verified, set `is_verified` and `rejection_reason` to `null`

**`is_verified` values:**

- `true` verified
- `false` rejected
- `null` pending

**The Rule:**
Create if not exists, Restore if soft-deleted.

Somehow i think my code is not ok and i'm overthinking or anything else (as a perfectionist + imposter syndrome).

**Migration**

```php
Schema::create('gateways', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignId('user_id')
        ->constrained()
        ->onUpdate('cascade')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->string('title', 50);
    $table->text('description');
    $table->string('website')->unique();
    $table->enum('wage', Gateway::getWageKeys());
    $table->text('rejection_reason')->nullable();
    $table->boolean('is_verified')->nullable()->default(null);
    $table->boolean('is_blocked')->default(false);
    $table->boolean('first_payment')->default(false);
    $table->dateTime('free_until')->nullable();
    $table->softDeletes();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Controller**

```php
/**
 * Create a new gateway.
 * 
 * @param  \App\Http\Requests\StoreGatewayRequest  $request
 * @return \App\Http\Resources\GatewayResource
 */
public function create(StoreGatewayRequest $request)
{
    try {
        $gateway = DB::transaction(function () use ($request) {
            $gateway = $request->user()->gateways()->onlyTrashed()
                                   ->where('website', $request->website)->lockForUpdate()->first();

            if (! $gateway) {
                return $request->user()->gateways()->create($request->validated());
            } else {
                if ($gateway->is_blocked)
                    abort(452);

                $gateway->fill($request->validated());

                if ($gateway->isDirty('website') || $gateway->isDirty('description')) {
                    $gateway->rejection_reason = null;
                    $gateway->is_verified = null;
                }

                $gateway->deleted_at = null;
                $gateway->save();

                return $gateway;
            }
        });
    } catch (QueryException $e) {
        if ($e->errorInfo[1] === 1062) {
            abort(409);
        } else {
            throw $e;
        }
    }

    return new GatewayResource($gateway);
}
```

Comment: I think you could move the blocked and and verified part of the logic to eloquent events. All those error numbers don't really mean anything to me. Constants could make the code more readable. Http status constants already exist somewhere in HttpFoundation.

Comment: Also I'm not sure about `$gateway = DB::transaction`. I think just `DB::transaction` works fine. Personally I prefer the other way to do transactions (`beginTransaction`, `commit`, `rollBack`)

Comment: As for using the database lock: Is it really that important in this case? Can the user accidentally do the same update twice? If he does, are there any consequences like getting charged money twice or wil the databse throw a unique constraint violation?

Comment: `$gateway->deleted_at = null; $gateway->save();` can be replaced with `$gateway->restore()`

Comment: @IGP If you read the code once again, the updated `$gateway` object inside the transaction is returned because `return new GatewayResource($gateway);` needs it as a response to the request.

Comment: @IGP When a user is selecting then updating the record, There's a chance that i may verify or block the gateway (after user's `select`,  before user's `save()`). So i don't want conflicts here. You can also convince me.

Comment: @IGP Will `restore()` also save the changes?

Comment: I've never used this syntax for transactions so I missed that return statement. It's fine if you want to keep using locks. Personally I only use them when dealing with payments to avoid the possibility of overcharging. [`restore()` should also save the changes](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/SoftDeletes.php#L108).

Comment: Try using [http status constants](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/5.4/Response.php#L24) for your errors. You should be able to access them from the `Illuminate\Http\Response` class. `Response::HTTP_CONFLICT` instead of 409 for example. HTTP 452 doesn't really exist, so I assume that's one of your custom status codes. Adding a comment in the catch block to state `$e->errorInfo[1] === 1062` is a unique constraint violation would also make the code more readable.

Comment: @IGP Thanks, I created a helper function called `catch_duplicate_entry_error` for the error `1062`. i simply do `catch_duplicate_entry_error($e); // abort(Response::HTTP_CONFLICT) or throw $e`